# Product Attribute value not displaying on frontend or backend

Tags: attributes, import, product-attribute, attribute-set

I have a specific *attribute* in a specific *attribute set* that is not saving correctly. Looking in the database tables `catalog_product_entity_int` and `eav_entity_attribute`, everything appears normal: `catalog_product_entity_int` holds the correct value of the problematic attribute.

However after saving the product, even though the value is changed correctly in the database, the value on the backend and frontend remain blank. No errors are logged or displayed.

[image: This attribute saves correctly, but does not show the saved value]

It appears to be only this specific attribute in this specific attribute set. I have added the suspect attribute to a different attribute set and it saved properly. I am also able to properly save other attributes in the problematic attribute set.

I'm hoping that maybe theres a table that is somehow missing a row that I can just fill in and get things back to normal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
Here is a quick overview of the table rows that show all the correct values in the correct places...

`eav_attribute`

```
| attribute_id | attribute_code  | backend_type | frontend_input | frontend_label  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 175          | connection_type | int          | select         | Connection Type |
```

`eav_attribute_set`

```
| attribute__set_id | attribute_set_name       |
------------------------------------------------
| 68                | Fiber Optic Patch Cables |
```

`eav_attribute_group`

```
| attribute_group_id | attribute_set_id | attribute_group_name       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1381                | 68              | Singlemode Simplex Jumpers |
```

`eav_entity_attribute`

```
| entity_type_id | attribute_set_id | attribute_group_id | attribute_id |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4              | 68               | 1381               | 175          |
```

and a sample product from `catalog_product_entity_int`

```
| entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 4              | 175          | 0        | 3723      | 958   |
```

and for reference, the associated value from `eav_attribute_option_value`

```
| value_id | option_id | store_id | value |
-------------------------------------------
| 5371     | 958       | 0        | SC/ST |
| 5372     | 958       | 1        | SC/ST |
```

**EDIT 2:**
Updating as I find potentially useful information, since this attribute is related to a project I'm working on. This attribute works as expected in advanced search, and also in layered navigation.

**EDIT 3:**
I created the bounty on Friday when I left the office; and now I am back in the office on Monday and the issue appears to have resolved itself. All products are correctly displaying their assigned values, and the attribute saves correctly. There are no cron jobs running on the server, and I had refreshed the index and cache many times while trying to troubleshoot the issue. I'll award the bounty to anyone who can give a reasonable explanation to this sorcery.

Comment: I agree with you that a table (somewhere) is not being updated. Have you tried to delete the attribute and re-create it? Also, what value are you trying to assign - boolean?

Comment: I don't want to delete the attribute, because then I would have to re-import all of the products that use that attribute. Its a standard dropdown with a number of values (not a boolean).

Comment: Have you added the options while creating the attribute

Comment: Try to print all the attributes before saving. then check your attributes and values. If its apear good to you, then print all the attribute before loading the Product Grid.

Comment: Have you changed attribute's `backend_type` in `eav_attribute` ?

Comment: What is the HTML output of your dropdown in the backend? Maybe the value of the dropdown-option is correct and the value is not loaded?

Comment: Try changing 'frontend_input' field to 'text' of the 'eav_attribute' table whether it shows some value or nor and report back

Comment: @AnnaVölkl Very good question; I happen to know that the values were loaded into the select options... however now that I am back in the office monday morning, the issue appears to have resolved itself! There are no cron jobs, and the index nor the cache had been refreshed since my last attempt when I created the bounty. Very strange.

Comment: @mageUz see above comment... issue appears to solved itself without intervention...

Comment: You say, you refreshed the cash, but which cash ?
Magento cash or Magento cash + all other server cash that might be working with that Magento installation of yours?

Comment: it might have also been index related (product flat table)

Comment: @someGuyOnTheWeb Magento's Cache. Server has APC. All other attributes and products appeared to be updating correctly, so I suspect it had to do with an error in Magento's indexing

Comment: @JulienLachal Thats my guess, but I wonder why Magento wasn't updating this attribute.

Comment: @andyjv who knows lol, Magento is sometimes moody.

Comment: Did you try to recreate the attribute delete/create?

Comment: @MageWH I did not, and I was avoiding having to do that because then I'd have to re-import all the products that use that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Are there more than one installations(test, dev, etc...) of the Magento in same server for staging? If you configure APC cache in the app/etc/local.xml with same prefix for all of them, probably they share cache and this could be cause of the problem above until APC cache purged:

`local.xml` of A installation

```
<global> 
    ....
    <cache>
        <backend>apc</backend>
        <prefix>SAME_PREFIX</prefix>
    </cache>
</global>
```

`local.xml` of B installation

```
<global> 
    ....
    <cache>
        <backend>apc</backend>
        <prefix>SAME_PREFIX</prefix>
    </cache>
</global>
```

Comment: Only one installation on this server